# Migration from tslint

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, eslint, tslint

How can I uninstall tslint -globaly, and use eslint as a default in my angular projects.
When, for example I use

```
ng new myProj
```

I want to have eslint.json, but not tslint.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by the angular cli at the moment because a lot of the custom lints that angular uses need to be ported to eslint and the typescript-eslint plugin.

This is the repo where the work is being done to migrate to eslint https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint.